# How to prove this function has a horizontal tangent line at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

> If $f$ is the function defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}xe^{-x^2-x^{-2}}&\text{if $x\neq0$},\\0&\text{if $x=0$},\end{cases}$$ at how many values of $x$ does the graph of $f$ have a horizontal tangent line?
>
> (A) None. (B) One. (C) Two. (D) Three. (E) Four.
>
> [(Image that replaced the text.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZSZr.png)

---

By solving the derivative of the function we get two solutions. But do we prove that the third solution is at $x=0$?

The answer is (D).

Answer (score 1):

Use the limit definition of derivative.

$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{xe^{-x^2-x^{-2}}}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac1{e^{x^2+\frac1{x^2}}}$.

Notice that $\frac1{x^2}\to\infty$ as $x\to0$, hence $e^{x^2+\frac1{x^2}}\to\infty$ and $\dfrac1{e^{x^2+\frac1{x^2}}}\to0$.

Thus $f'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac1{e^{x^2+\frac1{x^2}}}=0$ and $f$ does indeed have a horizontal tangent line at $(0,0)$.

Comment: superb!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!